# How to determine the color of an element using Java using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

How to determine the color of the button?
In my case, the standard button is **white**, but after I clicked on it, it turned **blue**. How can I check that it really turned blue?

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that color change is made by some css attribute like background-color, so just check it.

```
String color = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#dummy")).getCssValue("background-color");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the color change is only when the button is clicked and reverts the color on release then you have to use actions to click and hold on the button and then check the CSS value. Otherwise, you can just check the CSS value of the *background-color* attribute.

```
new Actions(driver).clickAndHold(btnCreateVRIPack).perform();
element.getCssValue("background-color")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement newBtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath(""); 
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(newBtn).perform();
System.out.println("Color of a button : " + newBtn.getCssValue("bg-color"));
```

Comment: Hi! While this may be an answer to OP's question, code only answers are discouraged on SO. Adding some context would help OP understand why this answer is sufficient, and it will help future visitor's to the site. Thanks!